# Which preposition is correct to anticipate the noun phrase 'Instagram post'?

Tags: prepositions

When we talk about photos, it's 'in' the correct preposition to use (see English Grammar In Use, p.248). However, is it 'in' or 'on' when expressing a situation like 'There is a beautiful woman in/on Jacob's Instagram post' ?

Thank you.

Comment: It should be "in".

Comment: It should be _a picture of a beautiful woman_, unless Instagram is more powerful than I suspected.